# Overlay should not be rotated when rotate the MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview, rotation

I am trying to rotate the MapView. And could rotate it just like this post:

[Rotate MapView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830391/rotate-mapview-in-android)

This works well. But I don't want to rotate the my custom Overlay(Created as "extends Overlay").

How to rotate the map without rotating Overlay ?

Thanks.

Comment: No suggestion on this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to counter rotate the overlay items.

Comment: i am not understand how to rotate overlay?