# Android Rotating MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, rotation

I am creating an application which trakcs down users path on a mapview. What I want to achieve when user takes a left turn for instance map should rotate it self in such a way that the head of the mapview should always point to upward direction. I hope that makes sense.

I came across Mr. Romain Guy's post an he says

> I have done this in the past and it
>   requires to create a custom ViewGroup
>   that rotates the Canvas in the
>   dispatchDraw() method. You also need
>   to increase the size of the MapView
>   (so that it draws enough pixels when
>   rotated.) You will also need to rotate
>   the touch events in
>   dispatchTouchEvent(). Or if you use
>   Android 3.0 you can simply call
>   theMapView.rotate() :

Does anyone came accross some solution similiar to my question ? A working example would be excellent :)

Comment: See my answer here: [Rotate MapView in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12126276/546054)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep in mind that it's not an ideal approach, because the text on the map is a static image and will rotate along with the map tiles (at some point it will be upside down).

Here's an example of how to put the `MapView` into your own `Layout` widget and rotate it. I've done it with the OpenStreetMaps, but it should be quite the same for Google Maps.

First create the "rotating" `Layout` widget

```
package com.eli.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class RotatingLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private final int mDiagonal;
    private float mBearing;

    public RotatingLinearLayout(final Context pContext, final AttributeSet pAttrs) {
        super(pContext, pAttrs);
        final DisplayMetrics dm = pContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        mDiagonal = (int) Math.hypot(dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
    }

    public void setBearing(final float pBearing) {
        mBearing = pBearing;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas pCanvas) {
        pCanvas.rotate(-mBearing, getWidth() >> 1, getHeight() >> 1);
        super.dispatchDraw(pCanvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int pWidthMeasureSpec,
            final int pHeightMeasureSpec) {
        final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(pWidthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(pHeightMeasureSpec);
        super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mDiagonal, widthMode), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mDiagonal, heightMode));
    }
}
```

Surround by it your `MapView` in the `layout.xml`

```
<com.eli.util.RotatingLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rotating_layout">
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</com.eli.util.RotatingLinearLayout>
```

Now, every time you receive a geo fix, update the bearing of the rotating layout and it should turn.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. I used your code to make a rotating layout and it works but the view is not centered. What i mean is the layout is bigger than the screen but it only exits the screen through the right side and bottom side. How would I go about centering the `RotatingLinearLayout`?

Comment: @bughi I think in dispatchDraw you'll have to some pCanvas.translate(x, y) to shift the canvas. However how to exactly compute x and y I cannot say.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that worked for me to have a proper centering of the view

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas pCanvas) {
    int translateX = mDiagonal / 2 - screenWidth / 2;
    int translateY = mDiagonal / 2 - screenHeight / 2;

    pCanvas.translate(- translateX, - translateY);
    pCanvas.rotate(-mBearing, mDiagonal / 2, mDiagonal / 2);

    super.dispatchDraw(pCanvas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example at installation of android sdk

```
android-sdks/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google_inc_-8/samples/MapDemo
```

But maybe you have to change a bit two method to get right orientation on touch event.

```
private class RotateView extends ViewGroup implements SensorListener {

/* ...  */

    private Matrix invertedMatrix = new Matrix();
    private float[] tempLocation = new float[2];


    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.rotate(mHeading, getWidth() * 0.5f, getHeight() * 0.5f);
        canvas.getMatrix().invert(invertedMatrix);
        mCanvas.delegate = canvas;
        super.dispatchDraw(mCanvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        centeringAllowed = false;

        float[] location = tempLocation;
        location[0] = ev.getX();
        location[1] = ev.getY();
        invertedMatrix.mapPoints(location);
        ev.setLocation(location[0], location[1]);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

This class is part of MapDemo project