# Rotating Google Map not MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation

I am writing an application using google maps. The main aim of this app is to show user location on map while he is moving. Here i want to show an arrow icon as user and the arrow must point in the user moving direction as shown in image.

[image]

So, here I have to rotate the map to make the arrow always showing upward when user turned. I tried some examples to rotate map but entire MapView is rotating, i am not getting map on entire screen. some area as dark and some area as map.

Is there any way to rotate map. If you know please reply me.

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028999/android-rotating-mapview

Comment: I've put an answer to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587851/how-to-rotate-the-map-while-changing-direction/17588142#17588142) (though you've probably already solved it yourself now). It's not been accepted but it is straight from the Google APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't violate the Google Maps Terms of service;
10.2 sub c:

> 10.2 Restrictions on the Types of Applications that You are Permitted to Build with the Maps API(s). Except as explicitly
>   permitted in Section 8 (Licenses from Google to You) or the Maps APIs
>   Documentation, you must not (nor may you permit anyone else to) do any
>   of the following:
>
> (a) No “Wrapping.” You must not create or offer a “wrapper” for the
>   Service, unless you obtain Google’s written consent to do so. For
>   example, you are not permitted to: (i) use or provide any part of the
>   Service or Content (such as map imagery, geocoding, directions,
>   places, or terrain data) in an API that you offer to others; or (ii)
>   create a Maps API Implementation that reimplements or duplicates
>   Google Maps. For clarity, you are not “wrapping” the Service if your
>   Maps API Implementation provides substantial additional features or
>   content beyond Google Maps/Google Earth, and those additional features
>   or content constitute the primary defining characteristic of your Maps
>   API Implementation.
>
> (b) No Business, Residential, or Telephone Listings Services. You must
>   not display business listings Content in any Maps API Implementation
>   that has the primary purpose of making available business, residential
>   address, or telephone directory listings.
>
> (c) No Navigation, Autonomous Vehicle Control, or Enterprise
>   Applications. You must not use the Service or Content with any
>   products, systems, or applications for or in connection with any of
>   the following:
>
> (i) real time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited
>   to turn-by-turn route guidance that is synchronized to the position of
>   a user's sensor-enabled device.
>
> (ii) any systems or functions for automatic or autonomous control of
>   vehicle behavior; or
>
> (iii) enterprise dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking
>   or similar applications. If you want to engage in enterprise dispatch,
>   fleet management, business asset tracking, or similar applications,
>   please contact the Google Maps API Premier sales team to obtain a
>   Google enterprise license. (If you are offering a non-enterprise
>   implementation, you may use the Google Maps API(s) to track assets
>   such as cars, buses or other vehicles, as long as your tracking
>   application is made available to the public without charge. For
>   example, you may offer a free, public Maps API Implementation that
>   displays real-time public transit or other transportation status
>   information.)

Comment: what you are telling is correct. I too know these things. I am learning android, just i want to know whether it is possible or not. I saw **Maps** applications in android market, there they are rotating google map as i mention, because of that reason only i am asking how to get that. Anyhow thanks for spending your valuable time for me.