# How to rotate the map while changing direction

Tags: android

I have integrated Google map in my application. I am able to find my current location.
I want map to auto rotate when i change the direction. How can i achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: Not an expert

Based on [Google API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#updating_the_camera_view), sounds like you need to adjust the bearing, such as described in [GroundOverlay#setBearing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay.html#setBearing%28float%29).

> **public final class GroundOverlay**
>
> A ground overlay is an image that is fixed to a map. A ground overlay
>   has the following properties:
>
> ...
>
> **Bearing**
>
> The amount that the image should be rotated in a clockwise direction. The center of the rotation will be the image's anchor. This
>   is optional and the default bearing is 0, i.e., the image is aligned
>   so that up is north.

Example:

```
GoogleMap map = ...; // get a map.
BitmapDescriptor image = ...; // get an image.
LatLngBounds bounds = ...; // get a bounds
// Adds a ground overlay with 50% transparency.
GroundOverlay groundOverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
   .image(image)
   .positionFromBounds(bounds)
   .transparency(0.5));
```

Comment: Actually, here's an answer already posted on SO entitled [Android-Rotating Mapview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028999/android-rotating-mapview). Complete with code but along the same lies as above. One of the answers also refers to sample code to do just this in the android sdk. Good luck!

Comment: But i am not using MapView. I am working on new api. GoogleMap.

Comment: Ah, ok, apologies for the misleading link then. In that case, I think the two references in my answer should provide a good lead. I'll add info to the answer.