# How to rotate map view with travel direction in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to rotate map view with user travel direction,I tried rotating it by using current location bearing but its not working I am not able to move forward on doing this.Can any one tell me how can I do this I am using google maps in my application.Thanks..

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028999/android-rotating-mapview

Comment: @lfor I tried that solution,there he was rotating basing on location bearing angle,but for me its not working correctly map is always rotating in different direction.

Comment: for the gps to give a good bearing you need to be moving... you can not test while still.  The alternative is to use the compass but then you have to make sure the user calibrates it which is hard in itself.  My users understand they have to be moving...

Comment: @lfor Thank u,I cannot use compass because it will be rotated based on device heading which is not reliable.I am testing the app while moving.