# Rotating image in Google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I using Google map in my android application,I am facing a problem in Google map,I want to rotate image in Google map relative to GeoPoint in Google map.
Just like this.
[click here](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_canvas.htm).

Your help will deeply appreciated.

Regards
Altaf

Comment: You can refer to similar question asked earlier [Rotate MapView in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830391/rotate-mapview-in-android)

Comment: I don't want to rotate whole MapView,I just want to rotate marker place on MapView.

Comment: What exactly do you have problem with? Displaying a View on top of MapView, animating View in a circle pattern, rotating a bitmap or something else?

Comment: As I have destination GeoPoint in Google Map I want to rotate a bitmap with respect to destination.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the MapOverlay class. Override the draw() method and draw what is needed. Look for other answers on stackoverflow to draw a rotated bitmap to canvas within the draw method. code snippet to get you started:

```
   class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
        boolean shadow, long when)
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(carloc, screenPts);

            //---add the marker---
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.marker);           
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
            return true;
        }
    }
```