# How to enable map rotation?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google maps app I can rotate map by sliding two fingers on the display. I would like to add this functionality to my app, but I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: A quick look at the API makes me think this may not be possible... the Maps source isn't open like the android source is.

Comment: Rotate the map in a `MapView` by using 2 fingers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830391/rotate-mapview-in-android might be a start

Comment: Is this a native Android app or a web-based app that uses the Google Maps JS API?  Your tags are ambiguous.

Comment: @josh3736, sorry, this is native java app. I have added java tag.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Sample Projects (API Demo) there is a map sample project called MapsDemo which you can find the solution for map rotation

Comment: +1 for pointing out that there are samples for the Google API at `android-sdk/addons/<api-level>/samples/`

Comment: I have tested MapsDemo (on htc one v - android 4.0.1) and it doesn't have this functionality. However, I'll investigate this code if it suppose to have it.