# Map rotation on smartphone

Tags: android, ios, google-maps-api-3, mapkit, osmdroid

We are developing an indoor application on iOS and Android using MapKit and Cloudmade for the mapping.

The mapping we have should be able to work both online and offline. My mapping expect is having troubles on how to make the map rotate to face the same way the user is facing.

So we are able to do real-time tracking and display it on a pre-plotted route on the map, but we need to have the direction the person is walking as displayed on the map to face the same direction the user is facing.

How can we do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The technique and Android SDK sample for Google maps described below also works for osmdroid.

[Rotate MapView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830391/rotate-mapview-in-android)