# Osmdroid map rotation

Tags: android, dictionary, rotation, tiles, osmdroid

I am doing osmdroid map project. I am using custom tiles for map. Can anyone tell me how to rotate the custom tiles map?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830391/rotate-mapview-in-android) ?

Answer (score 7):

The latest version of osmdroid includes the ability to rotate the maps.

```
mMapView.setMapOrientation(45.0f);
```

The latest samples application also includes a rotation gesture overlay for rotating the maps with a two-finger rotate gesture.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer sir. I am using shapefiles for map. This code just change the orientation only. It willn`t rotate the map.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying - are you saying it doesn't rotate the shapefiles? How are you adding them?

Comment: I am just convert the shapefiles into tiles using tilemill. The tiles used for map. So I can rotate the tiles(Map) for the purpose of the navigation. So kindly provide your suggestion and sample codes. Thank you Sir!!!!!!

Comment: If you call setMapOrientation it will rotate the maps including the tiles. If there is something specifically not working then you must clearly state what is not rotating properly. A screen shot would be the most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
RotationGestureOverlay mRotationGestureOverlay = new RotationGestureOverlay(context, map);
mRotationGestureOverlay.setEnabled(true);
map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
map.getOverlays().add(mRotationGestureOverlay);
```

Comment: Answers containing code only is bad answers. Add a description, please.

Comment: `RotationGestureOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView)` is now deprecated. Use `RotationGestureOverlay(MapView mapView)` instead.